# Its is possible to put some product on homepage (POPULAR) manually in prestashop?

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

How can I manage the content on the homepage in prestashop? Foe example I put a special product on **popular** tab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be solved through various ways,
One option is to custimize your product page from back office. That should be found in "theme module".

Another way you can try is to use third-party add-ons, that may not be costless.

Or you can edidt your source code, for example, your .tpl file.
Hope these can do some help.